# Getting an error: Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of substring function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a substring from the value of a column and I'm getting the following error `Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of substring function.`

The column type is NvarChar(50) and is a system column for an application, so I can't modify it.

Ideally I'd just be able to select the substring as part of the query without having to alter the table, or create a view or another table.

Here's my query

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(INVOICE__, ':', 1)
  FROM dwsystem.dbo.DWGroup
```

Im trying to select only everything in the string after a specific character. In this case the `:` character.

Comment: (1) The error seems obvious.  The second and third arguments to `substr()` are numbers.  (2) Tag with the database you are using.  (3) I would recommend that you ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `charindex` with `:` as the first argument

```
select substring(invoice__,charindex(':',invoice__)+1,len(invoice__))
  from dwsystem.dbo.dwgroup
```

Answer (score 1):

SUBSTRING parameter is start position and end position so both parameter will be number like below

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(INVOICE__, 1, 1)
FROM dwsystem.dbo.DWGroup
```

you can use SUBSTRING_INDEX as you used mysql

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(INVOICE__,':',-1);
```

example

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('mytestpage:info',':',-1); it will return   

info
```

Comment: Im trying to select only everything in the string after a specific character. In this case the `:` character. I've used this query in MySQL before but I'm still trying to figure it out in MS SQL

Comment: Looks like SUBSTRING_INDEX is not a recognized function in MS SQL, at least for my version.

Comment: @tdepiera1 The [MySQL substring function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring.asp) has the same signature as the sql server version. Maybe you meant [substring_index](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring_index.asp) - which does not exist in sql server.